Find an $a \times m$ submatrix of an $n \times m$ matrix with smallest rank
Given a matrix $n \times m$, I want to find the submatrices $a \times m$ by selecting $a$ columns such that their rank is minimal. Can this problem be solved efficiently?

Selecting one arbitrary column gives you rank 1.

Do you want to find one submatrix of all submatrices $a \times m$ with smallest rank? Is $a$ fixed too?

What's the size of $a$ compared to $n$? I haven't thought of this much, but it has an LWE/code decoding feel, so I'm not very hopeful

In a previous comment, now deleted, I said that the number of columns is fixed. I meant the number of row, that is $a$.

Let me say that a is between square root of n and n/2.
